Wanting to use an old Vuforia SDK in a Unity 2020 project
Got a legacy Unity 2020 project that I want to add Vuforia to. Version in PackageManager
says min version is 2020.3.
I've searched but can't find a repository of old SDK versions.
Does anyone know of the last Vuforia SDK version that was compatible with Unity 2020.3?
Also any issues working with this as (I'm guessing) I can't install via PackageManager. Also I'd be adding it to a project rather than starting from scratch.
Thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Regarding the second part of your questions there are a few ways you can add Vuforia to your project https://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started/vuforia-engine-package-unity . Still I would be cautious with using older Vuforia versions as they might not work well on newer devices or newer versions of iOS or Android.
